# Angular 1.x: OrderBy isn't ordering the dates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How we can use the 'filter' method to order the dates in the ascending order or decending order?

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"> 
</script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="orderCtrl">
<ul><li ng-repeat="x in dates | orderBy">{{x}}</li></ul>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('orderCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.dates = ["01/02/2018", "02/02/2018", "06/06/2018", "01/22/2019",     "12/12/2018"];
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Getting output as 
    01/02/2018
    01/22/2019
    02/02/2018
    06/06/2018
    12/12/2018

Excepted output
    01/02/2018
    02/02/2018
    06/06/2018
    12/12/2018
    01/22/2019

Comment: Why do you expect output in the later way? 22 is month?

Comment: It's in the format "mm/dd/yyyy". 2018 comes before 2019 and hence I'm excepting the output in that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the string to date and do the sort

```html
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"> 
</script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="orderCtrl">
<ul><li ng-repeat="x in dates | orderBy : sort : false">{{x}}</li></ul>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('orderCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.dates = ["01/02/2018", "02/02/2018", "06/06/2018", "01/22/2019","12/12/2018"];
$scope.sort = function(date) {
    var date = new Date(date);
    return date;
};
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```